# how to add new record to json file by Extjs?

Tags: json, extjs

i want to add data at the end of json file.I am confused.what I did is I add the following code to it but not working.

```
 PersonRecord= Ext.define('Persons',{
extend:'Ext.data.Model',
fields:[......]
});
 var ds=new Ext.data.Store({
    storeId: 'person',
    model: 'Persons',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '../data.json',
        reader:{
            type: 'json',
            root:'pers'
        }
    }
    });
    .....
    'id':Ext.id(),
    'fName':fName,
    'lName':lName,
    'fatherName':fatherName,
    'nationalCode':nationalCode,
    'tell':phone
    });
    ds.add(record);
    ds.commitChanges();
```

but dont work.
i can load data from json but can not add new record to json

Answer (score 1):

Ext JS is not going to update the .json file for you. If you are reading from an actual .json file, you'll need to have Ext JS send the new data to your server, and then have your server write out the update .json file.

If you can get away with supporting only very bleeding edge browsers, you could also conceivably use the HTML5(ish) File API to interact with file system items--here's a walkthrough: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Using this approach, you could conceivably create a custom Writer that could interact with the that API to persist additions, updates, deletes, etc.

Comment: I did a Google to see if someone's already done a custom Writer like this, but didn't see anything. Sounds like a fun weekend project :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to setup a Writer for your JsonProxy:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Proxy-cfg-writer